# React Redux - cannot use a pass down a component's method to the children - undefined error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I am trying to build  a todo list in React and Redux.
In my code below, I have a component with a function onDeleteItem. The problem is that I cannot pass onDeleteItem function to the sub-component Item. If I run this code, I get "Cannot read property 'onDeleteItem' of undefined" error.
However, if I try to pass that function outside the map function to a sub-component (to the Item component without mapping the state), it works.
There must be some strange binding problem.

```
class ItemList extends Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
    }

    onDeleteItem(event){
        var indexNum = this.props.items.indexOf(document.querySelector(".ion-trash-b").parentElement.textContent)

    }

    render(){
        var items = this.props.items.map(function(todo, index){
            return (
                <Item
                key={index}
                todo={todo}
                onDeleteItem={this.onDeleteItem.bind(this)} />
            )
        })
        return (
            <div>{items}</div>
        )
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the others already pointed out it's all about the context, luckily in ES6 they gave a bit more consistency to "this". I recommend using the new syntax if you have the chance to do so.

```html
render(){
    var items = this.props.items.map((todo, index) => {
        return (
            <Item
            key={index}
            todo={todo}
            onDeleteItem={this.onDeleteItem.bind(this)} />
        )
    })
    return (
        <div>{items}</div>
    )
}
```

I think using the ES6 arrow syntax should bind the correct context

Answer (score 2):

The problem is, as Borjante mentioned, that **the context changes inside the mapping function**. `this` is not pointing to the react component.

You could use an arrow function, however this requires you to transpile the code to ES5 since many major browsers don't support this syntax feature yet.

Instead, you can also **bind the context of the mapping function manually**, which should also solve your issue:

```
var items = this.props.items.map(function(todo, index) {
    return (
        <Item
            key={index}
            todo={todo}
            onDeleteItem={this.onDeleteItem.bind(this)} />
    )
}.bind(this))
```

Comment: Or simply pass context to `Array.prototype.map` as the second argument, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map

Answer (score 0):

i think the problem that you have is related to the this.props.items.map. You map with a regular function, and in that case the `this` keyword don't reference to the component anymore. If you use a arrow function inside map or you put .bind(this) and the end of the function inside the map. The method most go down the children

Answer (score 0):

You are inside and here this points to the current object in the map.
You can also use fat arrow functions.

```
class ItemList extends Component{
constructor(props){
    super(props);
}

onDeleteItem(event){
    var indexNum = this.props.items.indexOf(document.querySelector(".ion-trash-b").parentElement.textContent)

}

render(){
    var items = this.props.items.map(function(todo, index){
        return (
            <Item
            key={index}
            todo={todo}
            onDeleteItem={this.onDeleteItem.bind(this)} />
        )
    }.bind(this)
    return (
        <div>{items}</div>
    )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Noone has mentioned that you are currently creating function per child item while you need single function per `ItemList` instance. As [Official Docs](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/reusable-components.html#no-autobinding) recommend the most performant way is to bind your handlers in constructor.

```
class ItemList extends Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props);

        // bind method once per ItemList instance
        this.onDeleteItem = this.onDeleteItem.bind(this);
    }

    render(){
        var onDeleteItem = this.onDeleteItem

        var items = this.props.items.map(function(todo, index){
            return (
                <Item
                key={index}
                todo={todo}
                {/* you don't need this here */}
                onDeleteItem={onDeleteItem} />
            )
        })
        return (
            <div>{items}</div>
        )
    }
}
```